# how to get list of all databases in a mongo instance using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

how to get the list of all the databases in a mongo instance to a variable using pymongo?

for example to send following command to mongo instance using pymongo,

db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } )

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [database_names](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html?highlight=mongoclient#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.database_names)

```
dbs = MongoClient().database_names()
```

As Andrew Allaire points out: **Starting in pymongo 3.6** database_names() has been deprecated in favour of [list_database_names](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.6.0/changelog.html).

```
dbs = MongoClient().list_database_names()
```

Comment: thank you :) 
can you please share if we have any good online resources working with pymongo?

Comment: The [tutorials](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html) and [examples](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/index.html) on the official site are great

Comment: NOTE: Starting in pymongo 3.6 database_names() has been deprecated in favor of list_database_names(). https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.6.0/changelog.html

Comment: what about pymongo 3.4?