# pyMongo MongoDB Query for all databases

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to run the same query for all databases

`

for example

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost")

db["*"]["test"].find()
```

or

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost")

db["db1","db2","db3"]["test"].find()
```

To put it bluntly, how to run this logic in mongodb

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost")

db_names = db.list_database_names()

for x  in db_names:
   db[x]["test"].find()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get list of all databases in a mongo instance using pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501503/how-to-get-list-of-all-databases-in-a-mongo-instance-using-pymongo)

Comment: No , i need run query for all databases

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have to issue one query per database. What are you trying to do here? The `.find()` queries in your example are empty, are you trying to export data or are you looking to find a value and don't know what collection it is in?

Comment: @user20042973 Each clone has the same documentation name and databases are created by users. Frankly, I need to send the same query to all databases, I can do this with a simple code with python, but I want to send it as a mongo db query.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do that. Every query is specific to a collection. Via aggregation (eg `$unionWith`) it is possible to query multiple collections within the same database at once, but nothing across databases.

Comment: @user20042973 I just updated the post writing a sample python code. I just want mongo dbin to do this

Comment: Like I said, I am pretty sure it is not possible to do this in MongoDB. But I'm following the question to see if someone suggests otherwise.

Comment: @user20042973 If such a thing is not done, I think I will open a new database named root_copy, create a copy of the same data in the collection and collection created by all users, and search there...

Answer (score 1):

There are no commands to run the same query on multiple databases in a single command.

You can get the list of databases and repeat the same command by iterating the `list_database_names()` method which you can run against the MongoClient instance, e.g.

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
collection = 'mycollection'


for x in client.list_database_names():
    print(client[x][collection].count_documents({}))
```

Comment: Python is slow here if there are billions of databases.

Comment: If you have billions of databases, the speed of python is the least of your problems.